# How to set a List's Default Content Type (order) by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I've spent a lot of time Googling and MSDNing on this topic and then stopped at the **set_uniqueContentTypeOrder** method.

This method will take an array of Content Type IDs and change the "New Item" sequence of the Content Types in your list.

But I can not make it work. Every time I call this method on my list's root folder, I always get an error message says "something is wrong". And when I dig into the log file for the detail, I can only see a "Null reference" error message.

So, does anyone know how to set a List's Default Content Type (order) by using Javascript? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example will reverse the order, works for me:

```
var c = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var folder = c.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(<list title>).get_rootFolder();
c.load(folder, 'ContentTypeOrder');
c.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  folder.set_uniqueContentTypeOrder(folder.get_contentTypeOrder().reverse()); 
  folder.update();
  c.executeQueryAsync();
});
```

Comment: Hi eirikb, thanks! It does changes the default content type (order). But weird things happened: Once I added any columns from the 'new' default content type, the AllItems.aspx page will show an error message that "unable to display this web part." Any clue?

Comment: OK, I have figured it out: The new content type has the title column which conflicts with the default Item Title column. Once I removed the new content type ID column from the default view, it works now.